# How to install Railgun on AWS EC2 (with Amazon Linux installed)?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I have a problem with installing Railgun listener on AWS EC2 of ELB.

I followed this instruction:
https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/railgun/installation.html

So, what I did:

1. Accessed the ec2 via Putty.
2. Installed the new key using this command:

   $ sudo rpm --import https://pkg.cloudflare.com/pubkey.gpg
3. And then I was not sure how to add Cloudflare yum repository, because there seemed to be no relevant description about it.
   So, I added a Redhat linux repo using this command:

   $ sudo rpm -ivh http://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-release-latest.el7.rpm
4. Then I tried to install Railgun using this command:

   $ sudo yum install railgun-stable

But I got 404 Not found error. Here’s the screenshot:
[image]

The error message is:

```
http://pkg.cloudflare.com/dists/2018.03/main/binary-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Please let me know **how to install Railgun on Amazon linux instance**?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: OK, I will, thanks for the note. @jww